# How to add basic auth using retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, basic-authentication

I already search all around the places on internet how to add basic auth using retrofit2 but still no luck. I already implemented a simple login mechanism but basic auth must be use in order for successful login.

My model

```
public class ResObj {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

ApiUtils.java

```
public class ApiUtils {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "xxxxx";

    public static UserService getUserService(){
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(UserService.class);
    }
}
```

RetrofitClient.java

```
public class RetrofitClient {

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(String url){
    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
    }

    return retrofit;
}
}
```

UserService.java

```
public interface UserService {

    @GET("login?username={username}&password={password}")
    Call<ResObj> login(@Path("username") String username, @Path("password") String password);
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
private void doLogin(String username, String password){
        Call<ResObj> call = userService.login(username, password);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResObj>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResObj> call, Response<ResObj> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    ResObj resObj = response.body();
                    if(resObj.getMessage().equals("true")){
                        Intent intent = new Intent(TextLoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(TextLoginActivity.this, "The username and password is incorrect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else{
                    Toast.makeText(TextLoginActivity.this, "Error! Please try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResObj> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(TextLoginActivity.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Did you try [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit)

Comment: @Napster, not working for me. if possible, not too far with my code.

Comment: what response are you getting back

Comment: not authorize because no basic auth.

Answer (score 1):

As I see your login API request, it exposes the user's password and the username in the query. The least you can do is maybe encrypt it. But a much better solution would be to have a `POST` request instead of a `GET` request with the username and password in the body. You add the `Authorization` header to the API request as follows:

```
public interface UserService {
    String authorization = "Authorization: Basic XXXXXX";
    String contentType = "Content-Type: application/json";

    // Static Header

    @POST("login")
    @Headers({
            contentType,
            authorization
    })
    Call<ResObj> login(@Body UserCredential userCred);

    // Dynamic Header

    @POST("login")
    Call<ResObj> login(@Header("Authorization") String basicAuth, @Body UserCredential userCred);
}
```

The Body model can be:

```
public class UserCredential {
    private String username, password;

    public String getPassword() {
       ...encrypt your password here...
       return encrypted_password;
    }

}
```

Also, it is safe to put a null check before you do this: `response.body();` in the API response.

Comment: btw my main concern is basic auth, not the input username and password given by user. so your answer is about basic auth or login? if yes, where I need to put this?

Comment: @MohammadNurdin please check the API, I have added the Authorization header. This is a static header you can also add a dynamic one too.

Comment: i will try it first

Comment: btw I'm not really understand how to embed into my existing code. can show me the full code based on my coding?

Comment: It's simple just add the headers to your APIs in your interface. I have updated the code.